# Why do we keep saying "rama naam satya" while carrying a dead body for funeral?

Tags: practice, rama, death

Why do we only say about the *Rama* naam during the funeral though we have various gods in hinduism. Is there any specific story behind this?

I've never heard anyone pronouncing the names of lord Shiva or lord Vishnu, but it would make sense if people calls the name of lord Shiva as he is a god of Death.

So why people keep pronouncing the name of lord Rama?

Comment: If you keep on chanting "rama rama" it actually sounds like "mara mara satya hai" so thats somewhat related to this, like this person is now died and thats true, also, I don't think chant is a right word here, we can refer to as "taking name" or "calling him"

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's not "Rama Rama satya hai" its "Rama naam satya hai" so I don't think they are similar, though I agree with you with the word chanting usage here..let me edit it

Comment: When Ram was leaving Ayodhya for Satya to forest, it was as good as journey of dead body from Kaikeye's pont of view but people surrounding Ram were knowing that it was the journey for Satya. So they all were chanting "Ram kaa Naam Satya Hai"

Comment: "lord Shiva as he is a god of Death" - I don't agree to this phase. Yamraj is the god of Death, Lord Shiv is the god of Destruction (for re-creation). My suggestion is that you do some reading/research on this because this itself is a vast topic and cannot be explained here.

Comment: In regions like Kashmir mahadev Jay jay shiv shambo is said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Anything without the name RAMA has no value

Name Rama is equivalent to the Omkar naadbrahma. When you recite your soul is ready to have mukti.

> Ram nam Satya hai
> Satya bolo mukti hai

There is a chance that the Atman(soul) of the particular Jeeva(person) which has just passed away will get free from the sansaar chakra(World), if recited by others who are performing last rituals. Hence this is like a giving best wishes to the atma(soul) of the dead person. The continuous chattering in a loop implies that the dead body is no longer a truth (has no breath) which is the name RAMA. Anything without the name RAMA has no value, whatsoever. In Ramayana, Hanumanji also broke mala given by sita because Rama's name was not written on it.

### Glory of Rama name in Sages and scriptures

According to Gita 9th Adhyay If we speak name of Lord, we succeed in individual and universal blossoming.

Rama Nama gets exactly the same importance in Saguna Upasana (worshipping the Absolute Truth as a Being with a form) as does the Pranava ('Om') Mantra in Nirguna Upasana (worshipping the Absolute Truth as formless).

Rishi Manu shows that the Rama Nama has links to all the other mantras that ever exist.

In Syavana Smriti (Syavana is the name of a rishi), Syavana says that the Rama Nama is the essence of all the Vedas, Shastras, Itihasas and Puranas.

The chief among the Mantras for the Shaivites is the Panchakshari (5 lettered) mantra, 'Om Nama Shivaya'. Without the letter ‘ra’, ‘Narayana’ would read as ‘Nayana’ that means one without a way (‘gati’); without the letter ‘ma’, ‘Namasivaya’ would read as ‘Nasivaya’ that means inauspicious.

So the jiva akshara (life giving letters) 'Ra' and 'Ma' of these two Mantras are put together to form the Rama Nama!
Anyone chanting this Divine Name thus worships both Shiva and Vishnu at the same time.

#### Connection with Yoga

From source [namadwaar](http://www.namadwaar.org/articles/gloryoframanama.html):

> In the philosophy of the Yoga, 'Ra' is considered the 'Mooladhara' (the point of origin of the power of Kundalini) and 'Ma' is the 'Sahasrara' (the destination). Hence, when the Rama Nama is chanted in the right tone and manner, the serpent power rises and hits the head or the 'kapala' Thus, by merely chanting the Rama Nama, one can become a Yogi.

So people speaks it for dead person's soul who is connected to the origin (Supreme soul) .

### Another story related to Rama name,

Before writing Ramayana Rishi Valmiki was a thief and pirate named as " Valiya lutera". Sage Narada suggested him to chant **Mara Mara** whose opposite is Rama Rama. Valmiki started and he became sage out of the pirate and Lord Rama blessed him to write Ramayana.

It is truth that by chanting name of Rama everything can be accomplished.  (This is my own experience that the things I deserve, if I do not get, by chanting the holy word Rama, I am always able to get.)

### People's experience

Mahatma Gandhi united the whole india by chanting of Rama only, and Lord Hanuman is worshiped in **Hanuman Chalisa** to have `Rama Rasayana` means Rama names chemical that is generated from brain because of Rama name chanting and create power in the body.

Rama name itself is a truth, and when person dies he goes from Mriyu lok to Satya lok, so chanting of Rama's name gives peace to soul, even Ravana said Rama's name when he died!!!

Rama name is the home for people like me.

### Rama name is given highest priority

Lord Krishna may be considered as *Purushottama*, But Lord Rama was a **Maryada Purushottama**, means the best person living in community. one step above lord Krishna. Both are the one, but difference between examples provided by Lord Vishnu. It is said in Ramayana that just one name of Rama effects 10 times taking name of Vishnu.

### Trust level

There is also a trust level which is highest for Lord Rama, In india we say

> leave it on Ram Bharose, means leave it on the trust on Rama.

People also **seek** to have a son like Rama, non other any deity. Rama only.

People give way to troupe carrying dead body by just hearing Rama nama Satya he. And also chant the name of Rama and wish peace for the dead person's soul.

This name is holiest word and its chanting creates holy vibrations for soul.

Comment: 1.some times it happens that while chanting the name it becomes mechanical.. like shriram-shriam-shriram (fastly) approx 70-80 times in a minute.. So does this gets count ??

Comment: 2. Some old age people do japa while watching tv serials...in this particular case their mind is not on shriram ,its on tv serial's story , but their mouth is continuosly uttering Shriramm.. Does it helpfull?

Comment: Please try to answer my both questions.. if not atleast one.

Comment: You should chant or japa with "MAn Karma Vachan" means with mind body and soul then and only it is helpful. even single time saying shri ram gets count. God is best listener.

Comment: means at the time of chanting it should be in Mann (mind) also. Then only it will get counted.Right?

Comment: yes, mind body and soul.

Comment: was actually confused, since was reading http://www.swaminarayan.org/essays/2001/0812.htm this article which states god's name chanted knowingly, unknowingly does its effect..

Comment: @Sagar Yes, Lord's name will grant merit even uttered knowingly or unknowingly.Here unknowingly is key means Ajamila said Narayana but he actually called his son. Even you say his name with out full devotion still you get some punya. But it should not be out of carelessness or attachment to worldly things like TV serials. That is hypocrisy.God is Antaryami. Finally , those who take Lord's name with devotion and shraddha get better results.

Comment: From which time period does this ritual had started ? Or what did people recited before the birth of Rama during vedic period? @Ravi Shankar Kota

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh, Ram nam existed in Vedas. Sages used to do Ram nam before Lord Rama incarnated. So, Ram nam is recited since vedic period. Mharshi Vasistha named Lord Rama purposefully as Rama. There are 2 Taraka mantras - One is Om and Other is Ram. In Kasi, Lord Siva gives Rama taraka to people about to die and bestows them Moksha.