# Origin of "Rãma Nãma Satya Hai"

Tags: scripture, rama, culture, death

> *"Rãma Nãma Satya Hai"*

> *"राम नाम सत्य है"*

i.e.
The name of Ram is the truth, is commonly chanted by Hindus while carrying a dead body to be cremated.

What might be its scriptural origins? Is it a universal practice within all hindu cults? How prevalent is this practice, across various Samprãdayas (सम्प्रदाय) of Hinduism?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we keep saying "rama naam satya" while carrying a dead body for funeral?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/why-do-we-keep-saying-rama-naam-satya-while-carrying-a-dead-body-for-funeral)

Answer (score 2):

**शिवे शवे न सञ्चारो भवेत् प्रेतस्य कस्यचित् ।
अतस्तद्दाहपर्यन्तं रामनाम जपो वरम् ॥**

Rudrayamal tantra

There should be no communication of any ghost soul in the dead body, that is why the name of Ram should be chanted till the fire is lit.

**शवसाधनवेलायां रामनाम विवर्जयेत् ।।**

Pretsadhna tantra

It is absolutely prohibited to take the name of Ram while doing Shav Saadhana (शव साधना).